# shinyTree: view without selecting

Tags: r, shiny, shinytree

Consider the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stselected=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stselected=TRUE))) 
  })
})
ui <- shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    h4('Shiny hierarchical checkbox')
    ,shinyTree("tree", checkbox = TRUE)
  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

How can I make this so that by default, **none** of the above are selected but are **still displayed**?

If I set both `stselected = FALSE` in the above code, I get

[image]

which is **NOT** what I want; I would just like the above with the checkboxes deselected.

Links to online references on further documentation with code would be extremely helpful. The package documentation for `shinyTree` is not helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in such way :

```
output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    sss=list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stopened=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stopened=TRUE)))
    attr(sss[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE 
    sss
  })
```

## P.S

Documentation is realy bad... I find `stopened` in `shinyTree:::getJSON` which used in `shinyTree:::listToTags`

Comment: This is a great answer and saves me lots of effort.