# conditionalPanel based on ShinyTree selected value

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinytree

As I have complained various times on this site ([shinyTree: set variable to value if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209411/shinytree-set-variable-to-value-if-checkbox-is-checked/39211211#39211211), [shinyTree: view without selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207559/shinytree-view-without-selecting)), there is a serious lack of documentation on `shinyTree`.

Consider the following code in `R`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
ui <- shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    h4('Shiny hierarchical checkbox'),
    shinyTree("tree", checkbox = TRUE),
    # slider
    sliderInput("slider_input",
                                          "Slider",
                                          min = 0,
                                          max = 100,
                                          value = 0,
                                          step = 0.1,
                                          width = '100%'),
                              width = 8)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    sss=list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stopened=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stopened=TRUE)))
    attr(sss[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE 
    sss
  })

})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I am interested in having the `sliderInput` appear if and only if `I.1.1 lorem impsum` in the tree is selected.

I know that when using `checkboxGroupInput`s, I can use what is found at [conditionalPanel javascript condtions in shiny: is there R %in% operator in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637285/conditionalpanel-javascript-condtions-in-shiny-is-there-r-in-operator-in-java). This is all fine and dandy, but due to the lack of documentation (and the lack of questions asked on this site) about `shinyTree`, I am uncertain how to pursue this problem. **I understand I need to use a `conditionalPanel`, but I have no idea how to refer to the tree and its nodes in the `condition` argument of the function**. What complicates matters more is that the tree itself is not in the `input` (since it doesn't have the `input$` when declaring it), and I can't reference `output$` variables, to my knowledge.

I do know that the `condition` has to be written in JavaScript, but this is useless if I have no idea how to refer to the tree and its nodes.

Comment: You can use shinyjs and show\hide or render your slider on server side with if condition.

Comment: @Batanichek If I wanted to render my slider with the `if` condition, what would I use? I imagine there's not a `renderSlider()` function.

Comment: @Batanichek I imagine I would have to use something like `output$slider <- reactive({ if(--some tree node with condition--){renderSlider({sliderInput("slider_input",
                               "Slider",
                               min = 0,
                               max = 100,
                               value = 0,
                               step = 0.1,
                               width = '100%'),
  width = 8)})}})` but, again, it's the problem of referring to the tree node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render slider on server side

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
ui <- shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    h4('Shiny hierarchical checkbox'),
    shinyTree("tree", checkbox = TRUE),
    # slider
    uiOutput("slider_ui"),

    width = 8)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    sss=list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stopened=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stopened=TRUE)))
    attr(sss[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE 
    sss
  })
  output$slider_ui=renderUI({
if('I.1.1 lorem impsum' %in% get_selected(input$tree)){
  sliderInput("slider_input",
              "Slider",
              min = 0,
              max = 100,
              value = 0,
              step = 0.1,
              width = '100%')
}
  })


})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

shinyjs variant

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinyjs)
ui <- shinyUI(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    h4('Shiny hierarchical checkbox'),
    shinyTree("tree", checkbox = TRUE),
    # slider
    sliderInput("slider_input",
                "Slider",
                min = 0,
                max = 100,
                value = 0,
                step = 0.1,
                width = '100%'),

    width = 8)
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$tree <- renderTree({ 
    sss=list(  'I lorem impsum'= list( 
      'I.1 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.1.1 lorem impsum'='1', 'I.1.2 lorem impsum'='2'),stopened=TRUE),  
      'I.2 lorem impsum'   =  structure(list('I.2.1 lorem impsum'='3'), stopened=TRUE)))
    attr(sss[[1]],"stopened")=TRUE 
    sss
  })
observe({
  if('I.1.1 lorem impsum' %in% get_selected(input$tree)){
    show("slider_input")
  }else{
    hide("slider_input")
  }
})

  })



shinyApp(ui, server)
```